# How to solve both mongoose's overwrite problem and type writing

Tags: typescript, mongoose

To inject a type into the Mongoose user model, we typed

```js
import {
  Document,
  Model,
  ObjectId,
  PopulatedDoc,
  Schema,
  model,
  models,
} from 'mongoose';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';

interface DBUser {
  userId: string;
  password: string;
  email?: string;
  company?: string;
  refreshToken?: string;
  expiredAt: Date;
  followers: PopulatedDoc<Document<ObjectId> & DBUser>;
}

interface DBUserDocument extends DBUser, Document {
  getEmail: () => string;
}

interface DBUserModel extends Model<DBUserDocument> {
  findUser: (userId: string) => Promise<DBUserDocument>;
  findAllUsers: () => Promise<DBUserDocument>;
}

const userSchema: Schema<DBUserDocument> = new Schema(
  {
    userId: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    email: String,
    company: String,
    refreshToken: String,
    expiredAt: Date,
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

userSchema.pre('save', async function (next) {
  const saltRounds = 5;
  this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, saltRounds);
  next();
});

userSchema.methods.getEmail = function () {
  return this.email;
};

userSchema.statics.findAllUsers = async function () {
  return await this.find();
};

userSchema.statics.findUser = async function (userId: string) {
  return await this.findOne({ userId });
};

const User = model<DBUserDocument, DBUserModel>('User', userSchema);

export default User;
```

However, the following error occurs on the server.

```
Error [OverwriteModelError]: Cannot overwrite `User` model once compiled.
```

Modified the model code as follows to prevent overwrite errors.

```js
const User: Model<DBUserDocument, {}, DBUserModel> =
  models.User || model<DBUserDocument, DBUserModel>('User', userSchema);
```

However, this time, the static method is not recognized and cannot be used.
I've been trying to solve the problem all day, but I can't find a solution. How to use static method while solving overwrite error

============== additional message

Mongoose version is 7.3 and I'll show you an example where I tried to use a static method.

```js
export default {
  Mutation: {
    addUser: async (
      _: unknown,
      { userId, password, email, company }: IUser
    ) => {
      const signedUser = await User.findUser(userId);
      if (signedUser)
        throw new GraphQLError('User already exists', {
          extensions: { code: 'BAD_REQUEST' },
        });
   },
};
```

I tried to use the findUser static method to use user data with a specific ID in addUser Mutation. However, as above, a message was displayed saying findUser could not be found in the User model.

Comment: What error did you get  when you try to use the static method?

Comment: @Lin Du No error occurs and it says there is no static method in the User model.

Comment: More precisely, if you try to use the findUser method, 'Model<DBUserDocument, {}, DBUserModel, {}, Document<unknown, {}, DBUserDocument> & Omit<DBUserDocument & { ...; }, keyof DBUserModel> & DBUserModel, any>' type has no 'findUser' property. pops up a message.

Comment: What's the mongoose version? Where and how did you use the static method? Show the code

Comment: @LinDu Added examples of where and how to use mongoose static methods in the body.